# Remove margins on Wordpress theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, margins

I'm using Wordpress and I currently have installed Tesseract theme on my site: (http:// instantiwebs . com)

I would like to remove left/right margins on everything, like this site did it: http://tyler.com/. It is using also the same theme.

I've looked through the CSS style and can't seem to find the right section to edit. The stylesheet is located here: http://alexardavin.com/instantiwebs.com/wp-content/themes/Tesseract/style.css

Help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this code to the bottom of the stylesheet, it should work for you.

EDIT: Make sure you have the !important statements.

```
#site-banner {
    max-width: 100%!important;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
#footer-banner {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
#site-banner-right {
    right: 20px!important;;
}
```

Comment: Omg, thank you so muuuuuch!!! This and the My Custom CSS helped me like you don't have an idea!! Thank you thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use the free plugin Wordpress My Custom CSS.

It is light, and for small CSS edits you don't change the theme source code.
It prevents your edits to be overrided when you update.

Comment: Thank you so much sir!!! You really make it easy for me to add the code that Blake posted, you really saved me, thanks a lot again!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
body .site {
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

try above code

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir, but I cannot find the body .site { on my css... Which body do you refer to?